# Elastic search sub queries

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch

Still trying to get my head around searching joined tables in elastic search.  We have mongodb and its connecting to elastic search through the mongo connector.

I have two related collections in mongodb; people and images. There will be 8 million people and 20 million images.  Generally people have up to 20 images.  As follows:

```
people: [ 
  {
    id: ‘123456abc’,
    name: ‘john’,
    town: ‘San Diego’,
    ssn4: '1234' 
  }, 
  {
    id: ‘919645xyz’,
    name: ‘pete’,
    town: ‘Oxford’,
    ssn4: '1234' 
  }
]

images: [ 
  {
    id: ‘901’,
    contentType: ‘image/tiff’
    documentType: ‘signature’,
    peopleId: ‘123456abc’ 
  }, 
  {
    id: ‘123’,
    contentType: ‘image/tiff’
    documentType: ‘signature’,
    peopleId: ‘123456abc’ 
  },
  {
    id: ‘456’,
    contentType: ‘image/tiff’
    documentType: ‘mail’,
    peopleId: ‘123456abc’ 
  }
]
```

I want to be able to perform a DSL query that returns the images where the documentType = 'signature' and for people living in the town 'San Diego' and have an ssn4 of '1234' (or for a bonus, people who's town contains 'San').

Comment: How are you building your elastic search indexes?  Are you nesting images under a person?

Comment: Unfortunately no - we have mongo-connector which synchronizes the data automatically from mongoldb to elastic search in two separate collections within elastic search.

Comment: What you're trying to do can't be done unfortunately